# Get the number of returned results from Autocomplete jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I got the following piece of code

```
$("#UserSearch").autocomplete({
    source: "search.php",
    minLength: 2
});
```

Here a user enters an email and I seek it through the database, but I need to find the moment when the autocomplete stops getting results. For example I got user@example.com and user2@example.com. If the current user seeks "user3" and the page no longer returns results how can I catch this moment so that I may display another element on the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider to check the number of displayed elements in the `open` event, if the `len` is 0 you can display another element accordingly.

Other solutions are to use a custom `_renderItem` function or a custom extended widget, but in this case this can be a simpler solution.

Code:

```
$("#project").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: projects,
    open: function (event, ui) {
        var len = $('.ui-autocomplete > li').length;
        $('#count').html('Founded ' + len + ' results');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/DZ9zU/

### UPDATE

Better using [`response`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-response) event:

> Triggered after a search completes, before the menu is shown. Useful
>   for local manipulation of suggestion data, where a custom source
>   option callback is not required. This event is always triggered when a
>   search completes, even if the menu will not be shown because there are
>   no results or the Autocomplete is disabled.

Code:

```
$("#project").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: projects,
    response: function (event, ui) {
        var len = ui.content.length;
        $('#count').html('Founded ' + len + ' results');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/DZ9zU/1/

Comment: The problem is that open is not executed unless results are found. To do this trick you got to use the event "response".

Comment: Yes I'm just writing the solution of using response event, updated